# Filter taxonomy terms in common to nodes related to the viewed node

Tags: views, entities

I want to filter taxonomy terms in common to nodes related to the viewed node, but I cannot figure out how. What I am getting are all the terms that the related nodes have (with repeated terms too). Please take a look at this [recipe page, side block STAG RICETTA](http://www.mercatoagricultura.it/ricetta/tzatziki-greco)

I am filtering *seasonality* terms (months) in common to *ingredients* nodes (the ones related to the node being viewed) used in a *recipe* node (the viewed one).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't completely understand what you're trying to show. What do you mean by "filtering"? How are the nodes related to one another?

Comment: I'll try to clarify, maybe it's my poor english, sorry. I would be able to prepare that recipe only when all ingredients are available! thus I want to show the month in which ingredients needed (1st block in the sidebar, from top) are all available but I get all the month in which any of the ingredients is available.

Comment: ingredients are related to recipes by a "recipe_uses_ingredient" relation. seasonality of the ingredients is a taxonomy vocabolary having months as terms.

Comment: So you want to show, when viewing a recipe, a list of the seasons on its ingredients? Am I understanding correctly now?

Answer (score 1):

To show a list of season terms on the ingredient nodes related to the recipe node:

1. Create a view of taxonomy terms of type season.
2. Add a relationship: `Taxonomy term: Content with term`
3. Add a relationship: `Entity Reference: Referencing entity (A bridge to the entity that is referencing Content via field_recipe_uses_ingredient)` via the relationship created in step 2.
4. Check "require this relationship".
5. Save.

Comment: thank you beth,  step 3: relationship not found... is it that I'm using 'relation' module, not 'reference' module? why do I need to relate to the User? how do I relate with the viewed node?

Comment: Oops, the 'user' thing was a cut and paste error. Use the content entity that applies, not a user.

Comment: thanks beth; your method (I edited it introducing relations) returns all the months that any product has, not the ones in common to all the products, as needed. would you suggest any alternative method or modification?

Comment: You'll have to add the relevant contextual filters as needed.

Comment: sure, i did it even if i didn't mention (gathering recipe's NID), but it doesn't help as a recipe may have more that one associated ingredient :(

Comment: I think you have to pass in the NIDs of the ingredients as multiple contextual filters to accomplish that.